# Back to top $ undefined

Tags: javascript

In my code I am getting this message "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". What does it mean and how would I go about fixing this error. Here is my code below...

```
var amountScrolled = 300;

$(window).scroll(function() {
if ( $(window).scrollTop() > amountScrolled ) {
    $('a.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
} else {
    $('a.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
}
});

$('a.back-to-top').click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 700);
return false;
});
```

Thanks,
Kamal

Comment: it means you haven't included jquery in your code

Comment: Or that you're loading jQuery after your code. If jQuery is loaded, have you tried to wrap your code within DOM ready event?

Answer (score 0):

The `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error generally indicates that the jQuery library hasn't been referenced prior to it being called.

You'll want to ensure that your reference appears before your `<script>` and that it is ready (so you'll want to wrap your code in a "document-ready" block as seen below :

```
<!-- Reference jQuery Here (example CDN reference below) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>
var amountScrolled = 300;
// Your document-ready block (will not execute until jQuery has been loaded)
$(function(){
     $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() > amountScrolled) {
            $('a.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            $('a.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
        }
     });
     $('a.back-to-top').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 700);
        return false;
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This has really help out